# How to use a specific C++ compiler with Python CFFI?

Tags: c++17, python-3.9, cffi

We have an existing large C++ project which we build using a wide range of compilers and their versions (msvc, gcc, clang).

I would like to add a Python wrapper around the unit tests of the project, preferably using the CFFI Python library.

I need to ensure that the CFFI uses the same compiler as the project itself. Is there a way to initialize the CFFI with a path to our C++ compiler?

[A meta question: did I set the correct tags for this question?]

Comment: I've just asked the person on CFFI issue tracker https://foss.heptapod.net/pypy/cffi/-/issues/560